# Delphi 10 Seattle FMX Canvas Draw Line Problem

Tags: delphi

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Panel1.Canvas.BeginScene;
  Panel1.Canvas.Stroke.Color := TAlphaColorRec.Red;
  Panel1.Canvas.DrawLine(PointF(0, 0), PointF(Panel1.Width, Panel1.Height), 1);
  Panel1.Canvas.EndScene;
end;

procedure TForm1.Panel1Paint(Sender: TObject; Canvas: TCanvas;
  const ARect: TRectF);
begin
  Panel1.Canvas.BeginScene;
  Panel1.Canvas.Stroke.Color := TAlphaColorRec.Blue;
  Panel1.Canvas.DrawLine(PointF(0, 0), PointF(Panel1.Width, Panel1.Height), 1);
  Panel1.Canvas.EndScene;
end;
```

What is the problem in my code in two way for draw line and is not the same.
The result of code
[image]
Red line and Blue Line not the same.

Comment: Thanks, result code image added.

Answer (score 6):

Why are you drawing on the Panel from outside of its `OnPaint` event? Don't do that! Outside of an active paint operation, a control's `Canvas` is not ready for drawing, so in this case you end up drawing on the Form instead of on the Panel, as your screenshot clearly shows.

If you need to draw on the Panel from outside of its `OnPaint` event, then save the relevant details somewhere off to the side as needed, trigger the Panel to repaint itself, and apply the details inside of the `OnPaint` event as needed.  By then, the Panel's `Canvas` will have been setup correctly for drawing on the Panel.

Answer (score 1):

my guess is that you need to change the code to the Button1Click to reflect the Panel's top/left for the starting point, not 0, 0.

```
Panel1.Canvas.DrawLine(PointF(Panel1.Left, Panel1.Top), PointF(Panel1.Width, Panel1.Height), 1);
```

Comment: the coordinates 0, 0 for PANEL1Paint is within the Panel, the coordinates 0, 0 in Button1Click is the Form's coordinates